# "Less fast" vs. "less faster"

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives

Which one is correct?

> - He runs less fast than I.
> - He runs less faster than I.

Comment: Closevotes for "General Reference" should be accompanied by a link to a general reference, or one should be easy to find. "General Reference" means the answer is in an online source. It does not mean "too simple" or "general knowledge".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Faster" is already a comparative, so to add another comparative "less" onto it would be incorrect.

However, why not just use "slower"? "Less fast" sounds awkward even if it is technically grammatically correct.